# public key distribution python

Tags: python, encryption, public-key, pycrypto, pki

So I am currently working on a messaging application in Python with the use of the sockets library. I have made an echo server and a simple client which allows sending messages. These messages are obviously sent to all connected users.

The next thing I want to do is to make my application secure by encrypting my messages with asymmetric encryption. To learn about encryption in Python I have made a couple of python scripts using pycrypto.

The thing I cant quite figure out is how I can or should distribute the keys. In a messaging application with several untracked users which connects and disconnects all the time, how do I generate both public and private keys so that I can successfully implement a asymmetric encryption such as RSA? And how can I make this work using python?

I am fairly new to pycrypto and encryption in general so any suggestions or corrections are greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is too broad to answer and doesn't *yet* have much to do with programming. I would suggest that you ask a more detailed version of this question on [security.se]. You would need to describe your requirements of how the clients are supposed to connect and establish identity and authenticity. Next you need to describe who you want to protect this from. It is really easy to protect the communication against passive attackers (just observe messages), but almost impossible to do this against active attackers (probe servers/clients, manipulate messages in flight).

Comment: Well I would argue for that it has much to do with programming. Even though I partially ask about the theory around the distribution processes, I do ask how I could implement it using python. Anyways, i'll ask the guys over on infosec! Thanks :)

Comment: It's better to get the theory straight and then come to Stack Overflow if you don't know how to implement it. Both programming and theory intertwined leads to a big mess that nobody wants to touch. Potential answerers are put off and you don't get an answer. It's best to compartmentalize.